# Specify object type in definition list input

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a function, I want to specify the object type inside the list I have as input.
In particular, I would like to require that all the elements type of that list (the one I have as input) are the one of the objet I have previously defined.

What I have tried is this (the function is inside a class).

```
def testInput(self,listType1:list[int],listType1:list[bool],listType3:list[<my_object>]) -> None:
  pass
```

The error that occours is the following.

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a way to obtain what I want?

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it can be this format `val: List[object]`. myobject is not a primitive type.

Comment: @uozcan12 : I have the same error also with only primitive types. Also `def testInput(self,listTarget:list[int]) -> None:` gives me the same problem.

Comment: If you are using Python 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8 then you need to `from typing import List` and use `List` not `list` for types.

Comment: I guess you are just using python < 3.9 which does not support that

Comment: @MattClarke : correct, using ` List` instead, it works.

Comment: @SimonHawe : you are right! My version is `3.7`.